# Pandas: Grouping rows with same key in one row

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I am trying to figure out how to group rows with same keys, having a set of common features containing a key in the group (groupped by id), a set of uncommon features, in one row.

Something like

```
  id  C1  C2  Uk  U1
0  x   1   2   3   4
1  y   5   6   7   8
2  x   1   2   9  10
3  y   5   6   3  11
```

Here the set of common features is `C1` and `C2`, the set of uncommon features is `Uk` and `U1` with the key for the groups being `Uk`.

In this example, the desired result is:

```
  id  C1  C2  Uk3_U1  Uk7_U1  Uk9_U1
0  x   1   2       4     NaN    10.0
1  y   5   6      11     8.0     NaN
```

Of course, their could have been a `U2` column (hi Bono!), but that makes the example harder to write because of the number of columns in the result would be bigger.

The code for generating this dataset is :

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
              'C1': [1, 5, 1, 5], 'C2': [2, 6, 2, 6],
              'Uk': [3, 7, 9, 3], 'U1': [4, 8, 10, 11]})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `pivot`+`join`

You can easily do that with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and using [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to combine with the original df:

```
new_df = new_df = df.pivot('id','Uk', 'U1')
                    .add_prefix('Uk').add_suffix('_U1').reset_index()

print(new_df)

Uk id Uk3_U1 Uk7_U1 Uk9_U1
0   x   4.0   NaN    10.0
1   y  11.0   8.0    NaN

new_df.join(df.loc[:,'C1':'C2'])

   id   Uk3  Uk7   Uk9  C1  C2
0  x   4.0  NaN  10.0   1   2
1  y  11.0  8.0   NaN   5   6
```

And in the more general case you want to pivot for multiple columns [C1...Cn], you could do as follows. Say for example you have the following df:

```
  id  C1  C2  Uk  U1  U2
0  x   1   2   3   4   5
1  y   5   6   7   8   2
2  x   1   2   9  10  10
3  y   5   6   3  11  11
```

You could do:

```
values_to_pivot = df.columns.difference(['id', 'C1', 'C2', 'Uk'])
new_df = df.pivot('id','Uk', values_to_pivot).reset_index()
print(new_df)

    id    U1               U2           
Uk        3    7     9     3    7     9
0   x   4.0  NaN  10.0   5.0  NaN  10.0
1   y  11.0  8.0   NaN  11.0  2.0   NaN

new_df.join(df.loc[:,'C1':'C2'])

    (id, )  (U1, 3)  (U1, 7)  (U1, 9)  (U2, 3)  (U2, 7)  (U2, 9)  C1  C2
0      x      4.0      NaN     10.0      5.0      NaN     10.0    1   2
1      y     11.0      8.0      NaN     11.0      2.0      NaN    5   6
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I have a lot of uncommon features (`U1`, `U2`, ... `U100`) ?
Is there a simple way to tell that I want to use all other features in `values` except the ones specified in the other arguments?

Comment: Yes but how can I do it?

Comment: I just added how to do it, @NicolasScottoDiPerto

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll accept it. But isn't there a simple way in pandas to list all column names except some particular by just having to  mention the particular names?
That would make my life easier in my particular case because the columns are not organized that way.

Comment: Ok @NicolasScottoDiPerto, yes :). You can do so with `df.columns.difference(['id', 'C1', 'C2', 'Uk'])`, which will give you a list with all columns except these.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: What's the difference between your proposition and the third one?
I am not sure now witch one is the best...

Comment: Well, they are different approaches to solve the problem. You might want to check the attached documentation of the pandas functions used in each case for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184421/discussion-between-nicolas-scotto-di-perto-and-nixon).

Answer (score 3):

#### [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table)

You can specify `index` and `columns` with `pd.pivot_table`:

```
# add string prefix to Uk series
df['Uk'] = 'Uk' + df['Uk'].astype(str)

# pivot data and add suffix to columns
res = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['id', 'C1', 'C2'], columns='Uk')\
        .add_suffix('_U1').reset_index()

# flatten MultiIndex columns
res.columns = [j or i for i, j in res.columns.values]

print(res)

  id  C1  C2  Uk3_U1  Uk7_U1  Uk9_U1
0  x   1   2     4.0     NaN    10.0
1  y   5   6    11.0     8.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.set_index(['id','C1','C2','Uk']).U1.unstack().add_prefix('Uk').add_suffix('_U1')
Out[223]: 
Uk        Uk3_U1  Uk7_U1  Uk9_U1
id C1 C2                        
x  1  2      4.0     NaN    10.0
y  5  6     11.0     8.0     NaN
```

To match your expected output , but not recommend

```
df.set_index(['id','C1','C2','Uk']).U1.unstack().add_prefix('Uk').add_suffix('_U1').reset_index()
```

Update

```
newdf=df.set_index(['id','C1','C2','Uk']).unstack()
newdf.columns=newdf.columns.map('Uk{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format) 
newdf
Out[236]: 
          Uk3_U1  Uk7_U1  Uk9_U1  Uk3_U2  Uk7_U2  Uk9_U2
id C1 C2                                                
x  1  2      4.0     NaN    10.0     4.0     NaN    10.0
y  5  6     11.0     8.0     NaN    11.0     8.0     NaN
```

Comment: also `.reset_index()` at the end.

Comment: @pygo for reshape problem , I would like to keep them in index ,for future convert back .

Comment: How can I scale this if I have not only `U1` but also `U2`, ..., `U100`?